# Simple for loop not working in Jekyll

Tags: html, ruby, for-loop, tags, jekyll

I can't figure out for the life of me why this won't work...

```
<p>
{% for game in site.data.games %}
    <span>{% game.name %}</span>
{% endfor %}
</P>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
 Liquid Exception: Unknown tag 'game' in games/index.html
```

And using this .yml in the _data folder...

```
games:
  - name: Game1
    platforms: { win32, win64, linux64 }
    distribution:
      here: null
      desura: http://www.desura.com/games/Game1
      source: https://github.com/mygithub/Game1
    description: cg/games/Game1/description.html
    release: 2013-06-23

  - name: Game2
    platforms: {win32, win64, mac, linux32, linux64, android, ios, ouya, web}
    distribution:
      here: null
      desura: null
      steam: null
    description: cg/games/Game2/description.html
    release: 2015-Q1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the correct syntax ;

```
<span>{{ game.name }}</span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, guess that's what I get for coding at 4am, lol.

Comment: Can you approve this answer ?

Comment: Oops, sorry it took so long. :(